# Deleting form values from cache using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am facing this bizarre problem in my asp.net mvc application:
In one page I am showing a table full of data of a model class. Each row of data has a Edit image `<img src='somesrc' onclick='fnClick({mode:'edit',..other params});/>'`.

In addition to that I've Add button also to populate the same model class mentioned `<a href='#' onclick=fnClick({mode:'add'});>Add</a>`.

I am using a form which I use both for Edit and Add operation, and I call same function written in jQuery for these two operations. This function is passed with a mode param depending on which button is clicked. This mode is used to either populate the values on edit or opening blank form for add. Now on the page if I click Edit first and then add, the add operation still shows the data of the Edit form. Is this a cache issue or something I'm missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the add button, find the form element, and reset it:

```
#('#myformid')[0].reset()
```